# How to keep show data when I use ' Show more / hide Button ' more than once not once time in - Django & JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates

How to keep show data when I use 'Show more / hide Button' more than once not once time in JavaScript.

My question is, how I can keep show more button work after it show all data at first time ,

I mean when user press on show more button and it show all item then he press on ' hide button' it will hide all posts right?

then user want show data again and press on show more again it must show data again why here don't do that?

I want keep show data and hide it many times not once

html page :

```
  {% for tech in techhome %}

  <div class="contact">
  <div class="card-deck">
  <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 800px;">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <a href="Tech/{{ tech.slug }}"><img style="height:100%;width:100%;border-radius:6.5px;" src="{{ tech.get_image }}" class="rounded float-right" alt="..."></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card-body">
          <a href="Tech/{{ tech.slug }}"> <h5 class="card-title" id="primary_site_pages_app_name_control"> <b>{{ tech.name }}</b></h5></a>
          <p class="card-text" id="font_control_for_all_pages">{{ tech.app_contect|truncatechars_html:153|safe}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
         <small class="text-muted" id="date_post_control">{{ tech.post_date}}</small>
         <small class="firstsmall"><a class="bg-orange" href="{% url 'tech' %}" id="tag_name_control">مقالات تنقية</a></small>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

{% endfor %}


<!-- show more button -->
<div class="text-center mt-4">
<a role="presentation" type="button" class="btn btn-lg loadMore" style="width:30%;color:white;background-color:#7952b3">show more </a>
</div>

<!-- hide  -->
<div class="text-center mt-4">
   <a role="presentation" type="button" class="btn btn-lg" id="hide" style="width:30%;color:white;background-color:#7952b3"> hide 5 posts </a>
</div>
<br>



<script>
// this for show more 
const thumbnails = $(".contact");
let visibleThumbnails = 0;

function showThumbnailsUntil(index) {
for (var i = visibleThumbnails; i <= index; i++) {
 if (i < thumbnails.length) {
    $(thumbnails[i]).addClass('visible');
    visibleThumbnails++;
 } else {
   break;
 }
}
}

showThumbnailsUntil(4);

$(".loadMore").on("click",function(){
showThumbnailsUntil(visibleThumbnails + 4)

if(visibleThumbnails === thumbnails.length)
{
   $(".loadMore").fadeOut(); //this will hide
   //button when length is 0

}
}) // end show more

// hide all posts 
$("#hide").on("click", function() {
  $(".contact:nth-child(n+10)").hide("slow");
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your given code you where increment value of `visibleThumbnails` whenever `show` button was clicked but , you never decrement its value to get exact number of visible divs that's the reason its not working after some time .

In below code i have first check if the value of `visibleThumbnails` is greater then `5` if yes then loop through divs to hide required divs and decrement that much divs from `visibleThumbnails` value.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(".contact").hide() //hide all contact div
const thumbnails = $(".contact");
let visibleThumbnails = 0;

function showThumbnailsUntil(index) {
  for (var i = visibleThumbnails; i <= index; i++) {
    if (i < thumbnails.length) {
      thumbnails.eq(i).show(); //show contact div 
      visibleThumbnails++;
    }
  }
}

showThumbnailsUntil(4);

$(".loadMore").on("click", function() {

  showThumbnailsUntil(visibleThumbnails + 5)

  if (visibleThumbnails === thumbnails.length) {
    $(".loadMore").fadeOut(); //this will hide
  } else {
    $(".loadMore").fadeIn(); //show 
  }
}) // end show more

// hide all posts 
$("#hide").on("click", function() {
  //get the total visible thumnails value
  var hiding_ = visibleThumbnails;
  //check if value is > 5 
  if (visibleThumbnails > 5) {
    //loop to hide divs - 5 
    for (var i = hiding_; i >= (hiding_ - 5); i--) {
      thumbnails.eq(i).hide(); //hide
      visibleThumbnails--; //decrement total visible value
    }
    $(".loadMore").fadeIn(); //show more 
  }


});
```

```css
.contact {
  background: pink;
}

.card {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contact">
  <div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 800px;">
      Soemthing1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="contact">
  <div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 800px;">
      Soemthing2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="contact">
  <div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 800px;">
      Soemthing3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="contact">
  <div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 800px;">
      Soemthing4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="contact">
  <div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 800px;">
      Soemthing5
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="contact">
  <div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 800px;">
      Soemthing6
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="contact">
  <div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 800px;">
      Soemthing7
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="contact">
  <div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 800px;">
      Soemthing8
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="contact">
  <div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 800px;">
      Soemthing9
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="contact">
  <div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 800px;">
      Soemthing10
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- show more button -->
<div class="text-center mt-4">
  <a role="presentation" type="button" class="btn btn-lg loadMore" style="width:30%;color:white;background-color:#7952b3">show more </a>
</div>

<!-- hide  -->
<div class="text-center mt-4">
  <a role="presentation" type="button" class="btn btn-lg" id="hide" style="width:30%;color:white;background-color:#7952b3"> hide 5 posts </a>
</div>
<br>
```

Comment: thanks it's work very good i just replace ' hiding_ - 5 ' with ' hiding_ - visibleThumbnails ' and work fine with my design